# How to add a string with (') in insert in to statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to manually add a item into my table in SQL Server by using `insert into` statements, but I get an error.

Normally a string is added using a single apostrophe in front and back of the string in SQL Server, but I am adding a value which has an apostrophe in between (like `can't`), how to add this in the T-SQL `insert into` statement?

I did try 3 different methods to insert but still failed

```
insert into orders (6, 'microsoft surface pro', 'IDHGHRTUJ'''123456', 1, 8)
insert into orders (6, 'microsoft surface pro', 'IDHGHRTUJ'123456', 1, 8)
insert into orders (6, 'microsoft surface pro', "IDHGHRTUJ'123456", 1, 8)
```

I need output in this of the string with the apostrophe in iot

Comment: use 2 single apostrophes:  `'IDHGHRTUJ''123456'`

Comment: @forpas i did try that method sir but it is showing error as invalid syntax )

Comment: Try this: `insert into orders values (6,'microsoft surface pro','IDHGHRTUJ''123456' ,1,8)`

Comment: Instead of building strings, use SQL placeholders in your program. See http://bobby-tables.com/ .

Comment: It's better and safer to mention the column names in the statement: `insert into orders (column1, column2, .....) values (6,'microsoft surface pro','IDHGHRTUJ''123456' ,1,8)`

Comment: As forpas mentioned, double quotes should work. Anyway, you can check with DECLARE @Var AS NVARCHAR(20) = 'IDHGHRTUJ''123456' and then INSERT INTO ORDERS (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (6,'microsoft surface pro',@Var ,1,8)

Comment: I remember that I had several problems in the past, so, depending on the SQL Server version you are using maybe it crashes. On that case you can find a workaround with an special character (I used ^) so, put that instead and replace when got in your front-end application. It is a bit arduous but may work.

Answer (score 7):

You can insert single quote in database by using double single quote while providing values as shown below:

```
create table orders (OrderId int, ProductName varchar(50), ProductDescription varchar(50), CatId int, GroupId int)
insert into orders values (6, 'microsoft surface pro', 'IDHGHRTUJ''123456', 1, 8)

select * from orders
```

Here is the output after insert

```
OrderId ProductName ProductDescription  CatId   GroupId
--------------------------------------------------------
6   microsoft surface pro   IDHGHRTUJ'123456    1   8
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/KYJW23198)

Comment: Here double single quote means two times single quote not the --- ".

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use CONCAT() within your insert statement.

```
 create table #orders (OrderId int, ProductName varchar(50), ProductDescription varchar(50), CatId int, GroupId int)
 insert into #orders values (6, 'microsoft surface pro', CONCAT('IDHGHRTUJ','''','123456'), 1, 8)
```

Used a temp table #orders for testing

```
select * from #orders
```